# Wordpress Is Saving Original Image Only

Tags: images

I have spent a few days wrestling with this issue. I have also searched for a similar question to no avail.

When I upload a new image, The only file being created on the server is the original image. (I am checking the upload folder through FileZilla.)

Then, when the image object is returned it has the same url for all image sizes.
Eg `$image['sizes']['thumbnail']` is the same as `$image['sizes']['large']`.

I've been draughted in to help on this project so I am not sure if a plugin is causing a conflict.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or does anyone have ideas on how I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

in `functions.php` in your theme

you can also use `add_image_size` function to add custom size

Comment: Thank you @Kika. Unfortunately, this didn't work. I even tried it with add_image_size (add_image_size( 'hard-crop-med', '400', '225', array( "center", "center") ); ) It's not even saving the standard 'thumbnail', medium' and and 'large'.

Comment: you should be sure in your theme `functions.php` file that NOT `remove_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Kika. Still no luck. For the sake of troubleshooting I downloaded the entire site through FTP and set up a similar environment locally using all the plugins that were used remotely. This worked fine leading me to think that it not an issue with theme support. Thank you all the same. I'll happily try any more suggestions you can think of, even if it is just to troubleshoot.

Comment: I should add that `remove_theme_support` was not in function.php and I can see that it was previously working by looking at the previous upload folders.